# Relatório RDL de Report Builder 3.0 com MVC 4

Tags: c#, mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-4, report-builder

Estou com um problema aqui, eu fiz um sisteminha em C# usando Razor MVC 4 com banco SQL Server 2014, até ai tudo bem... porém agora estou precisando gerar relatórios, eu fiz um relatório lá no Report Builder e adicionei ele na minha solução, ai criei os métodos:

```
public ActionResult ListagemDescricao(int IDDescricao)
{
    LocalReport relatorio = new LocalReport();
    relatorio.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Relatorios/RelatorioDatainicioDatafim.rdl");

    var query = db.OrdemServicos.Where(o => o.IDDescricao == IDDescricao).ToList();

    relatorio.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ToDataTable(query)));

    string reportType = "PDF";
    string mimeType;
    string encoding;
    string fileNameExt;

    string deviceInfo =
        "<DeviceInfo>" +
        "<OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>" +
        "</DeviceInfo>";

    Warning[] warnings;
    string[] streams;
    byte[] bytes;

    bytes = relatorio.Render(reportType, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExt, out streams, out warnings);

    return File(bytes, mimeType);

}
```

e

```
public DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
    PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
        BindingFlags.Instance);

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
    {
        dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
    }

    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        var values = new object[Props.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
        }
        dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
    }
    return dataTable;
}
```

só que agora preciso passar os parâmetros que criei lá no report builder para GET, no rdl tem o parâmetro de @IDDescricao , @Data e Data2 que são o ID da descrição que tenho cadastrada em outra tabela e elas são relacionadas do ID para o IDDescricao e também tem a data inicio e data fim do relatório, só que não consigo fazer eles funcionarem, alguém poderia me ajudar? eu queria fazer uma view onde eu pudesse escolher la no dropdownlist a descrição, e outros dois textbox onde poderia colocar a data de inicio e data fim do relatório, ai quando eu clicasse no botão ele iria abrir o pdf em outra aba, para download.

Comment: Só pra eu entender: você não está conseguindo imprimir os valores no relatório ou você gostaria de montar uma tela com os parâmetros para que você possa filtrar melhor seu relatório?

Comment: Estou tentando montar a tela com os parâmetros mas não sei como, eu tentei executar o relatório por GET, indo lá no navegador e chamando o metodo via pagina/ListagemDescricao?IDDescricao=1 , ele funciona porem com mais de 1 parâmetro não consigo fazer funcionar, lá no report builder eu coloquei os parâmetros certinhos, lá aparecem num campo acima do relatório para serem preenchidos

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que você deve fazer o GET por meio do link:

> pagina/ListagemDescricao?IDDescricao=1&Data=01/01/2014&Data2=02/01/2014

E na sua action de gerar o relatório você colocar os outros parâmetros também:

```
public ActionResult ListagemDescricao(int IDDescricao, DateTime data, DateTime data2){
    LocalReport relatorio = new LocalReport();
    relatorio.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Relatorios/RelatorioDatainicioDatafim.rdl");

    var query = db.OrdemServicos.Where(o => o.IDDescricao == IDDescricao).ToList();

    relatorio.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ToDataTable(query)));
    relatorio.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("Data", data.ToShortDateString()));
    relatorio.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("Data2", data.ToShortDateString()));
    //Continuar...
}
```